# How to make a collection view behave like a tab bar controller in terms of navigation?

Tags: swift

I need to use a collection view to duplicate what a tab bar controller does in an app to act as a main menu. this is because the tab bar is very hard to customise and the design requires it. but i need the cv to behave exactly like a tab bar controller in terms of navigation.

I have a view controller with 2 containers: one for the collection view and one for the child view controllers. 
When cv is init it has the first cell selected, which calls a function that adds a child VC with its own cv that controls what shown in a table. 
The problem is that every time the use taps on a cell in the main menu the function that I have gets a new instance of the child vc. so the user is not taken where he left of. the whole thing resets because I have a new instance. 
Below are the relevant code snippets shown: the cv subclass and code from the parent VC. Maybe a navigation controller will help me, although I still need to avoid creating a new instance. Maybe a boolean to check? Thats what I have thought about.

```
class MenusCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    var initialSetupPerformed: Bool = false
    var defaultSelectedMenuTab: IndexPath!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if !initialSetupPerformed && defaultSelectedMenuTab != nil {
            selectItem(at: defaultSelectedMenuTab, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
            initialSetupPerformed = true
        }
    }
}

lazy var programMainMenu: MenusCollectionView = {
        let mainMenu = MenusCollectionView(frame: self.mainMenuContainer.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        mainMenu.defaultSelectedMenuTab = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        mainMenu.delegate = self
        mainMenu.dataSource = self
        return mainMenu
    }()

func showMainChatTab() { 
        let rootVC = MainChatMenuVC() 
        rootVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(rootVC)
        self.view.addSubview(rootVC.view)
        positionChildController(child: rootVC)
        rootVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = programMainMenu.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! MainMenuCell
        let tab = mainMenuTabs[indexPath.item]
        cell.mainMenuTab = tab
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            showMainChatTab()
        }
        return cell
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedMainTab = indexPath.item // check here.
        switch selectedMainTab {
        case 0: showMainChatTab()
        case 1: print("p")
        case 2: print("c")
        case 3: print("w")
        case 4: print("s")
        default:
            print("no such main tab")
        }
    }
```

I need to keep track of the navigation so when the user changes from one main menu tab to another and returns he is returned where le left, and not at the root of the child VC. The code that I have now resets everything. 
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps using a container view instead of a collection, unless you want to be able to animate from tab to tab

Comment: ok, but how would that help solve my problem as described above?